# Storage Path not writeable in laravel with Intevention?

Tags: image, laravel, upload, storage, intervention

I'm getting a little confused here with this Storage VS Public paths in Laravel 5 > ... My understanding is one should use `Storage::` instead of `File::` for writing files to the Storage folder foresighting the use of cloud services like Amazon etc. So I am trying to put a jpg into a the `storage/app` folder using Intervention and this code:

```
 public function apply(Request $request)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        $path = '/users/'.$user->id;

        if (!Storage::exists($path))
        {
            Storage::makeDirectory ($path, $mode = 0755, $recursive = false, $force = false);;
        }


                Image::make($request->file('image'))
                    ->orientate()
                    ->resize(600, null, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    })
                    ->resizeCanvas(600, 600, 'center', false, 'ffffff')
                    ->save($path.'/foo.jpg');


    }
```

First of all I am not sure the `!Storage::exists($path)` will do anything as the API for storage tells it won't check for directories so how should I check if a Directory exists?? 
Second `dd(is_writable($path))`; return false, and indeed running that code results in

```
NotWritableException in Image.php line 143:
Can't write image data to path
```

error.
so how should this be done?

Comment: Does your storage directory has write permission?

Comment: I believe intervention SAVE function can't work here. Still I can't understand how to PUT the file to local disk using Storage after creating the $image object as $image = (intervention file)

Comment: use File facade instead of Storage. more info: http://laravel-recipes.com/categories/20

Comment: I was able to have Storage:: work. File will not work for cloud storage afaik.

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" that I used was manipulate the image directly in the temp path, and then save it in the storage folder using the Laravel storage method.

```
$tempFile = $request->file('image')->getRealPath(); 

Image::make($tempFile)
    ->resize(100, 100)
    ->save($tempFile); // Note that we are saving back to temporary path

// Now we can proceed and send the manipulated file to it's final destination
// in '/storage/app/public/uploads'
$path = $request->file('image')->storePublicly('public/uploads');
```